# SetDataSource in media player android

Tags: android

I have a class which is media player. I use `mp.setDataSource(path);` to get file from sdcard. But with this solution I get error. How can I change way to set Data to my player to work? I was reading about FileDescriptor. How can I change my path to use FileDescriptor?

This is error:

```
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:976)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at VoiceRecorder$7.onClick(VoiceRecorder.java:306)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17341)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 15:42:00.827: W/System.err(616):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-16 15:42:00.837: W/System.err(616):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-16 15:42:00.837: W/System.err(616):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616): Handler (android.media.MediaRecorder$EventHandler) {416bcf68} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.media.MediaRecorder$EventHandler) {416bcf68} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:618)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:587)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:558)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:495)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.postEventFromNative(MediaRecorder.java:977)
07-16 15:42:00.857: W/MessageQueue(616):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? What does your code look like? What kind of file is it?

Comment: You have to explicit set the length of your file. Use the overloaded method:
AssetFileDescriptor afd = ctx.getAssets().openFd([your asset name]);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
try {
    FileDescriptor fd = null;

    if (isInInternalMemory(audioFilename)) {
        int audioResourceId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(audioFilename, "raw", "com.ampirik.audio");
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = mContext.getResources().openRawResourceFd(audioResourceId);
        fd = afd.getFileDescriptor();
    } else if (isInSdCard(audioFilename)) {
        File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String audioPath = baseDir.getAbsolutePath() + audioFilename + ".mp3";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(audioPath);
        fd = fis.getFD();
    }

    if (fd != null) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This example is from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022506/play-mp3-sounds-from-sd-card) with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To play video file from **SdCard** u can use these one also:

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    String sdcardPath = "/sdcard/smaple.mp4"
    videoView.setVideoPath(sdcardPath);

    /** These one is controlling mediaplayer  */

    MediaController mediaControler = new MediaController(this);
    mediaControler.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaControler);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

sdcard format getting from ***DDMS/FileExplorer/SdCard/video***

**Must Remember:** VideoView only supporting *.mp4 & 3gp* video format

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget adding android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in you project AndroidManifest.xml